# Private inheritance visibility/access in C++

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, access-control, injected-class-name

Why does an interface have a special visibility in a method due to a private inheritance?

Note that a global specifier **::** is required in my derived class.

I don't understand why a method inherits some kind of visibility due to private inheritance. It's totally reasonable that Derived class doesn't have access to Control. But why doesn't it have access through a member either?

```
class Control
{
public:
    void ModifySomething();
};

class Base : private Control
{
private:
    virtual void Update( Control& i_control );
};

class Derived : public Base
{
private:
    // ----------↓↓
    void Update( ::Control& i_control ) override;
};
```

Note: I understand we could fix this by composition. But I would like to know why it's defined like that in C++. Could we break const-ness or something?

Comment: You seem to be asking multiple different questions. Can you edit your question so that it asks a single clear question?

Comment: what you mean by `But why also through a member?`

Comment: @Brian is it fine now?

Comment: @appleapple Fixed readability

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the C++ 17 Standard (14.1 Access specifiers)

> 5 [ Note: **In a derived class, the lookup of a base class name will
>   find the injected-class-name instead of the name of the base class in
>   the scope in which it was declared.** The injected-class-name might be
>   less accessible than the name of the base class in the scope in which
>   it was declared. — end note ]

And there is an example similar to your code snippet.

> [Example:

```
class A { };
class B : private A { };
class C : public B {
  A* p; // error: injected-class-name A is inaccessible
  ::A* q; // OK
};
```

> — end example ]

That is the injected class name of the private base class within the derived class definition hides the name of the base class defined in the namespace. And this injected name is private. So the derived class does not have an access to this private injected name.

Comment: That is the concept and explanation I was looking for: injected-class-name

Answer (score 3):

`class Derived` doesn't have access to anything `private` in `class Base`, so it doesn't have access to `class Control` through `Base`.  It can, however, access `Control` directly because it's declared in the same global scope as `Derived`.

As @formerlyknownas_463035818 comments, there are two paths to `Control` from `Derived` but one is blocked due to `private` access control so the other, global path, is chosen.

Comment: would be correct to say that `Control` is in scope via two different paths and the one that has to be prefered by the compiler is blocked, because it is private?

Comment: I don't understand why these two paths exist. Why is it defined like that in the language? private inheritance should be like it doesn't exist to the derived class. However, it does exist because I need to specify the global scope.

Comment: Because `Control` is in the global `namespace`, `private`ly inheriting it doesn't change that.